# Mongodb: How to chain functions together and obtain the results?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The following code chains mongodb functions together, however, the result is not returned. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
myApp.js:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  favoriteFoods: [String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var queryChain = function(done) {
  var foodToSearch = "burrito";

  Person.find({ favoriteFoods: ["burrito"] })
  .sort({ name: -1 })
  .limit(2)
  .select({ age: 0 })
  .exec(done(null, people));

};
```

Comment: looks like `people` is not defined. 
maybe you need something like
`.exec((people)=>done(null, people));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
var personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number,
  favoriteFoods: [String]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);

var queryChain = function(done) {
  var foodToSearch = "burrito";

  Person.find({ favoriteFoods: foodToSearch })
  .sort({ name: 1 })
  .limit(2)
  .select({ age: 0 })
  .exec((err, data) => {
     if(err)
       done(err);
    done(null, data);
  })
};
```